# Error validating: This line is not a valid field or attribute definition

Tags: prisma

I wonder why my **model** (the `Like`-model) does not work as I expect it to.

Maybe someone can explain?

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  likes Like[]
}

model Like {
  fromUser User @relation(fields: [fromUserId] references: [id])
  fromUserId Int
  toUser User @relation(fields: [toUserId] references: [id])
  toUserId Int
  @@id([fromUserId, toUserId])
}
```

The error reads: `Error validating: This line is not a valid field or attribute definition.`

It points at `fromUser User @relation(fields: [fromUserId] references: [id])` and `toUser User @relation(fields: [toUserId] references: [id])`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to model your relations in the following manner:

```
model User {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  likedUsers    Like[] @relation("likedUsers")
  usersWhoLiked Like[] @relation("usersWhoLiked")
}

model Like {
  id             Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  likedUser      User? @relation("likedUsers", fields: [likedUserId], references: [id])
  likedUserId    Int?
  userWhoLiked   User? @relation("usersWhoLiked", fields: [userWhoLikedId], references: [id])
  userWhoLikedId Int?
}
```

Whenever you have more than 1 relation to a model you need to provide a relation name to [disambiguate the relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations).

Also you need to store which users you have liked and who liked the current user. So you would need two relations for this.

Answer (score 1):

Missing commas.
The solution might look like this:

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  likes Like[]
}

model Like {
  fromUser User @relation(fields: [fromUserId], references: [id])
  fromUserId Int
  toUser User @relation(fields: [toUserId], references: [id])
  toUserId Int
  @@id([fromUserId, toUserId])
}
```